# Create tunnel on boot via remote connection

Tags: bash, cron, ssh-tunneling

Here is my situation:

A. I have a dashboard server that restarts several services on 6 linux servers remotely on click certain buttons.

B. I have multiple DB servers: two on dev, two on production.  Two Node servers

My script to connect one node to both db servers at once:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -f -N -L 3307:192.168.0.19:3306 -L 3308:192.168.0.20:3306 192.168.0.12 -luser
```

only works if I either type it in directly or from a shortcut in a script on the target server

What I am trying to do is have my script run in exec('./localdashbaordscript') while I reboot the server in question via the dashboard.

The problem is this script (./tunnel.sh) does not get run, neither by remote ssh from dashboard nor cron job.

crontab -e:

```
@reboot /home/user/sh/tunnel.sh
```

Any ideas and have I been clear?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you set its executability?

Comment: yes chmod +x tunnel.sh already applied - I can execute it on the target server directly, just not from the dashboard (separate server)

Comment: Are there any errors from this cron job? (They go to mail by default.) Have you checked if network is up already?

Comment: Thx for that heads up - I will dbl check the network settings and report back

Comment: fixed it with ssh $SERVER ~/sh/tunnel.sh rather than trying to run the command raw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to run

```
SERVER=$1
ssh user@$SERVER  'ssh -f -N -L 3307:192.168.0.19:3306 -L 3308:192.168.0.20:3306 192.168.0.12 -luser'
```

from the dashboard

what works is invoking the script on the target server with

```
SERVER=$1
ssh user@$SERVER '~/sh/tunnel.sh'
```